# Ordinary Differential Equation and Characteristic Equation: How to Identify Multiplicity of Roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble consistently identifying the number of roots (multiplicity of roots) when solving characteristic / auxiliary equations of higher-order ODEs.

Here's a basic example:
$$
\text { Solve } \frac{d^{4} y}{d x^{4}}+2 \frac{d^{2} y}{d x^{2}}+y=0
$$
The characteristic polynomial: $m^{4}+2 m^{2}+1=\left(m^{2}+1\right)^{2}=0$ has roots $m_{1}=m_{3}=i$ and $m_{2}=m_{4}=-i$.

My trouble here, and please excuse the detailed simplification, is when solving $\left(m^{2}+1\right)^{2}=0$ algebraically, my understanding is as follows:
$$ (m^2 + 1) = 0 \\ m^2 = -1 \\ m = \pm i $$

In other words: $ m_1 = i $ and $ m_2 = -i $. I don't see the multiplicity of 2 here but am clearly missing something. Even more specifically it's $m_1 $ and $m_3$ that are the same. Then  $m_2$ and $m_4$ also the same. Am I making a mistake in the algebra?

Comment: $(m^2+1)^2=(m+i)^2(m-i)^2$

Comment: This question is independent of the ODE's. You should retag as root of polynomials.

Comment: You don't see the multiplicity because you killed it yourself when simplifying from $(m^2+1)^2$ to $m^2+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first step you remove the square. To stay equivalent, you have to note that all multiplicities that are computed for the new polynomial need to be multiplied by $2$ to get the multiplicities for the old polynomial. Which means that the simple roots $\pm i$ of $m^2+1=0$ are double roots of $(m^2+1)^2=0$.

If the new polynomial had had a root of multiplicity $3$, then the original polynomial would have had the same root with multiplicity $6$, etc.